# save gps trajectories as pandas data

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have some files that contains trajectories data.
Some of the data is running some of it is cycling and some of it is walking.
I classified all of them and I want to load them to pandas to be able to classified new trajectories.
I have data that looks similar to that: [GPS Trajectories](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/GPS+Trajectories)

I can not find the right way to save the data in pandas. I can convert it to any format in csv file but what is the best way to load it to pandas?

Comment: what have you tried? `pandas.read_csv()` can load csv data into pandas DataFrame. See the documentation for parameters

Comment: I do not understand, I just checked and the files are .csv, and pandas has [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to load it. What is your doubt?

Comment: yes i tried it. but i need to manage multiple rows in go_track_trackspoints as they were one trajectories and therefor ther share the same label